# Python - save packets to pcapng file

Tags: python, scapy, pcap, pyshark, pcap-ng

My code creates a couple of packets using scapy and should save them to pcapng files.
However, I couldn't find any way to save the files as pcapng.
I tried using Scapy's PcapWriter and saving the files to `sniff.pcapng`, but the result is a pcap file with a pcapng extension.
Also tried looking for modules to convert the existing pcap file to pcapng, but couldn't find anything. (Found this [python-pcapng](https://pypi.org/project/python-pcapng/) module, but couldn't find any documentation about how to save a file I read)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Nadav!
I had to make some changes to make it work, So I'm adding the code in case anyone else will need it.

```
import pcapng.blocks as blocks
from pcapng import FileWriter
from scapy.all import *

SHB_INTERFACE_OPTIONS = {"if_description": "Hand-rolled","if_os": "Python"}
SHB_HEADER_OPTIONS = {"shb_hardware": "artificial", "shb_os": "python", "shb_userappl": "python-pcapng"}

shb = blocks.SectionHeader(options=conf.SHB_HEADER_OPTIONS)
shb.new_member(blocks.InterfaceDescription, link_type=1, options=conf.SHB_INTERFACT_OPTIONS)
    with open(f'{pcap_path}ng', 'ab') as file_obj:
        writer = FileWriter(file_obj, shb)
        orig_packets = rdpcap(pcap_path)
        for packet in orig_packets:
            spb = shb.new_member(blocks.SimplePacket)
            spb.packet_data = bytes(packet)
            writer.write_block(spb)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at [this](https://github.com/rshk/python-pcapng/blob/master/examples/generate_pcapng.py) from the library you linked to.
Seems like it is an example of creating a pcapng given a packet.